# VBA Search for Value in Userform

Tags: excel, vba, search

In my Workbook i have several shapes with many buttons, each button opens a userform.

Now a nice to have would be a search function which opens the Userform with the specific value. 
In fact i have no idea if this is even possible and if so how i could do that.

In the pictures below you can see my shapes, buttons and the userform.

[image]
[image]

For example, in the shape under WK-Mechanically, "Lehren konstruieren" is the "Task Name", and "Hr.Lutonsky" is the Responsibility. With the search function i should be able to search for one of these fields.

I would be very happy if someone could help me, or show me another way. I think it would be also okay if the searchfunction shows all data from the searched userform in another worksheet.

**EDIT:**

There should be a new Button with Caption "SEARCH", if i click this button there should be open a small userform with two fields "TASK NAME" and "RESPONSIBILITY".

Comment: The idea that I'm getting from your description is that you would like to be able to click 'Watch Work Package' and then enter a keyword to do a lookup by Task Name/Responsibility. And then, the list of work package in your userform is filtered to show only packages that match the keyword. Correct?

Comment: @kerwei sorry, forgot to write how it should be, but you are not so wrong at all, but the click on the button "Watch Workpackage" shows the whole Userform. I want a new Button for the search function. But the list of workpackages which match the keywords would be creat

Comment: Would you be familiar with event listeners? It should be straightforward using the event listeners on the button. Put a textbox together with your search button and then retrieve it by something like TextboxName.Value when your button is clicked. Looks to me like the tricky part is to manage the list of workpackages. If it's a full Excel solution, then I expect the list to be stored as a table in one of your sheets. A table with the following headers - (TaskName, Responsibility, PackageName)

Comment: unfortunately not .. but thanks for the information, i will read some documentations about it.